# unable to locate element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to locate the username input panel on this website:http://mail.qq.com
Here is the code I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://mail.qq.com")
delay = 3 
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id('u')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

Here is the error message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python27/3.py", line 10, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id('u')))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 285, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 787, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="u"]
```

Does anyone know what problem there is?

Comment: tried a longer delay?

Comment: not yet :) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication form located inside an `iframe`. To be able to handle `input` field you should switch to that `iframe` first:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://mail.qq.com")
delay = 3 

browser.switch_to.frame("login_frame")

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(('id', 'u')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

Comment: By the way, I'm new to programming, internet and stuffs. How could you tell that it was located inside an "iframe"? What's an "iframe"? And what does it do?

Comment: [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) it's an `HTML` element that contains embedded page. To check whether element located inside an `iframe` just check its ancestors in `DOM` and [handle it appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/4589/switching-frames)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown from `browser.find_element_by_id('u')`, the driver tries to locate the element before entering the expected condition. Since it doesn't exists yet there is `NoSuchElementException`.

In addition, [presence_of_element_located](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) should receive locator as parameter, not `WebElement`

```
 WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'u')))
```

Comment: Thank you. So, you mean I just need to wait longer?

Comment: @刘志伟 No, I say you need to change the way you are using the `wait` method to the way in my answer. Waiting longer won't help in the code you posted in the question, the error is not `TimeOutException`

Comment: Hi, I tried to use "By.ID" but I received a "name "by" is not defined" error. What package should I import?

Comment: @刘志伟 add `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`